# identify duplicate images using objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, image

I'm new to objective c , Currently I'm working with images , I need to remove duplicate images if any. Kindly do share your views on this.

Comment: Did you try -isEqual:?

Comment: u try in local image or web service image

Comment: Explain what do you mean by duplicate image: duplicate filename, or same content? The first one is trivial, the latter is tooooo broad (related to image processing)

Comment: i mean the same content for two png images. Their name may differ but apart from that all the content is same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may involve some image comparison algorithms if you want to have a good program.

Some basic checks before the image comparison that you can do:

1. file type/file size check
2. file dimension/resolution check
3. other properties that an image have can be retrieved and then compare

You can even compare the checksums before using image comparison algorithms.

Comment: Really? Did you try it?

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad you mean my last sentence or overall?

Comment: Kindly suggest me some image comparison algorithm.

Comment: OK, if objective-c has some existing classes to encapsulate the algorithm, then the life will be easy. I just put some basic ideas, i am not good at objective-c.

Answer (score 0):

You can compare their data using

```
NSData *img1Data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(<#UIImage *image#>);
NSData *img2Data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(<#UIImage *image#>);
if ([img1Data isEqualToData:img2Data])
{
     //same images
}
```

Comment: Someboady at Apple's should write this code and put it in a method called -isEqual:.

Comment: Let me try it.Thanks .

Comment: But when i try this method UIImagePNGRepresentation(), some times it will  throws an exception "ImageIO: PNG zlib error" , any idea guys. From my understanding I think this happens because of invalid png image file . Kindly correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Once you have a `UIImage`, it is capable of producing either a JPEG or PNG using `UIImageJPEGRepresentation` or `UIImagePNGRepresentation`. Most probably you are having something wrong with image. If you parsing images from a directory make sure that directory system files like `.DS_Store` is not parsed